# I Want to Link Plugin with My Post.How is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, post

I have a wordpress blog.I Want to add Facebook like Button &Facebook Share button & Retweet Buttons with My Post's Right Side.My Sample Blog Link Here [Click Here](http://bazarganmagazine.com/blog/) (Output). How to Modify like this?Now I think it's clear.while i installed plugin my theme has been modified.i can't re-set that.please help me..

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is a Social Media plugin. There are hundreds available.

Example: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-media-widget/

Comment: yeah,there are hundreds available but the position is not customizable  .so only i asked here.I want, the plugin to execute right side of my every post.